# How to update all fields form one table to another [MySQL]

Tags: mysql

I have two tables with a lot of fields

table - `A`
table - `B`

in table `A` only two fields are filled all other are empty, but exactly that fields are filled in table `B`

I would like to

`UPDATE A, B set A.c = B.c, A.d = B.d .... WHERE ....`

but there are a bout 100 columns, is there any way how to update all fields in `A` from `B` except 1 particular field ? Is there any way how to tell mysql left 1 particular fields in `A` as it is.

Comment: How about copying the first two columns to a temporary table. . Make a copy of tableB. . Add two columns in the new table and copy data from temp table. .

Comment: table A is production and it is filling everysecond ;( I can't lock it, rename etc...

Comment: Explain more about these two fields in `table A`. If you can't insert records with all column data into `table A` then use a trigger to get details from `table B`. Me think this is piling up redundant data and breaking normalization. Triggers gonna affect performance too.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? This one particular field in `table A` is a primary key in `table B`?

Comment: I had table A, before I made some changes, I did backup. Changes was not good, now I restore backup to new table, table B. So these two tables almost identical, except that table A is filling in real time by users, now I would like to roll back my changes... for that I would like to update ALL fields in table A with data from table B, but in table A there is 1 field which  I don't want to update from table B. And because there are a lot of fields i'm looking for a way without enumerating all of them

Comment: record count in both table is same? And what's so special about this 1 field which is not to be touched?

Answer (score 0):

If field name in table A and B are same then you can just use excel to build the string.

Copy the entire structure of DB table A into excel as 1 column and then use excel formula with string concatenation to build the required string.

It should not be that difficult task.

From MySql end, you can review  DELETE and INSERT option with help of temporary table. More details needed to think of solution at MySql end.